# Loadrunner: unique id(in POST request) correlation for ASP pages

Tags: asp-classic, correlation, loadrunner

I am new to both `ASP` and `Loadrunner`. Any help would be really appreciated.

I recorded signing into a site in `Loadrunner` twice to find the difference between two files so that I can capture dynamic values.

I found these,

- Difference 1:

File1:

```
web_submit_form("example.com", 
  "Snapshot=t43.inf", 
  ITEMDATA, 
  LAST);
```

File2:

```
web_submit_form("example.com", 
 "Snapshot=t43.inf", 
 ITEMDATA, 
 LAST);
```

- Difference 2:

File1:

```
web_submit_data("visualization.aspx_5", 
  "Action=https://example.com/Visualization/visualization.aspx?uniqueId=0.92737735625811826EC073E1-4128-E111-9FFB-00155D03A708", 
  "Method=POST", 
  "RecContentType=text/html",
```

File2:

```
web_submit_data("visualization.aspx_5", 
  "Action=https://example.com/Visualization/visualization.aspx?uniqueId=0.92737735625811826EC073E1-4128-E111-9FFB-00155D03A708", 
  "Method=POST", 
  "RecContentType=text/html",
```

1. In (Difference 1) I should not worry about snapshots right? Snapshot attribute is added by Loadrunner for snapshot view. Am I right? Or should I correlate them?  Forgive me if my questions are really stupid.
2. What is unique id in the above url? (Difference 2)
   I read about session id, jsession id… is unique Id similar to these? I did find unique ids for web elements but not sure what these unique ids are for url. Please could someone throw some light on this?
3. The unique ids were same when I recorded first and second time.  Third time I recorded, the unique ids were different. So, should I correlate these unique ids?
4. When I tried to correlate them, I could not find the unique id values in the previous requests to capture them. Where are these unique ids coming from? 
5. This question, I’m not sure if it’s related to Loadrunner or asp, but if anyone can answer it then it would be really helpful.

I am still learning `Loadrunner`. These `ASP` pages are from a `Microsoft CRM project`.
When I sign into the website, I see a “Sign Out” link on the top right corner. I even see the link html code using firebug. Below is the code
`<a class=" ms-crm-MastHead-UserInfo-SignOut ms-crm-MastHead-SignOut-Link" title="Sign Out" tabindex="0" href="#">Sign Out</a>`
But I don’t see this code in the `Loadrunner` snapshot response, so my text check for “Sign Out” fails
I am stuck and confused.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here?

I am learning Loadrunner, got stuck because of this issue, tried to solve it, read around a lot to solve it but nothign helped me. So,
I finally posted this question here. I have seen people asking much simpler questions and they get answered here.
Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. If I am then I will delete this post.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

about question 3 & 4, enable the complete log in run time setting or do it manually (not on LR)  VIEW - Source and get the RB and LB.
best way to learn is trial by error. so you are good as long as you work hard for it.